# Why pivot table changed the float display to something differently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, periscope

I want to change the table display format so I used `pivot_table` but final result is completely changed I don't know why.

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ('2015/1/1', 73.23234, 'salgrp'), 
        ('2015/2/1', 53.23234, 'salgrp'), 
        ('2015/3/1', 0.00, 'salgrp'), 
        ('2015/2/1', 30.3, 'salnic'), 
        ('2015/3/1', 10, 'salnic'), 
        ('2015/4/1', 31.2, 'saldsc'), 
        ('2015/5/1', 33.23234, 'saldsc'), 
    ], 
    columns=['date', 'amount', 'formula'])
df = df.round(2)
print(df)
df = df.pivot_table(columns=['date'], index=['formula'], values=['amount'])
print(df)
```

And here is the output.

```
       date  amount formula
0  2015/1/1   73.23  salgrp
1  2015/2/1   53.23  salgrp
2  2015/3/1    0.00  salgrp
3  2015/2/1   30.30  salnic
4  2015/3/1   10.00  salnic
5  2015/4/1   31.20  saldsc
6  2015/5/1   33.23  saldsc
          amount                                    
date    2015/1/1 2015/2/1 2015/3/1 2015/4/1 2015/5/1
formula                                             
saldsc       NaN      NaN      NaN     31.2    33.23
salgrp     73.23    53.23      0.0      NaN      NaN
salnic       NaN    30.30     10.0      NaN      NaN
```

My question is why pivot table result changed and how to maintain two decimal places across all the result. ? Final result should comes like this `0.00 and 31.20 and 10.00`

Answer (score 1):

Internally, they are still `float` and have the same values. If you do want to see them in two decimal places and you are using Jupyter Notebook, you can use `style.format` (without `print`)

```
(df.pivot_table(index='formula', columns='date', values='amount')
         .style.format("{:.2f}")
)
```